# how to apply dynamic field validation only for specific fields in angular 2+

Tags: angular, typescript

here i am trying to implement dynamic form validation i.e only for specific fields as i can implement dynamic validation but out 5 fields i want to implement only for  those fields which i mentioned names.

say like  i have fields name like **firstname,lastname,age,gender**  & i have a array like **first name,gender** now what i want is the fields which are there are array has to be validated not all fields how can i achieve that

below is my sample code

```
**.html**

<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
                <h2>Angular 6 Reactive Form Validation</h2>
                <form [formGroup]="registerForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>First Name</label>
                        <input type="text" formControlName="firstName" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.firstName.errors }" />
                        <div *ngIf="submitted && f.firstName.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                            <div *ngIf="f.firstName.errors.required">First Name is required</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Last Name</label>
                        <input type="text" formControlName="lastName" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.lastName.errors }" />
                        <div *ngIf="submitted && f.lastName.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                            <div *ngIf="f.lastName.errors.required">Last Name is required</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Email</label>
                        <input type="text" formControlName="email" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.email.errors }" />
                        <div *ngIf="submitted && f.email.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                            <div *ngIf="f.email.errors.required">Email is required</div>
                            <div *ngIf="f.email.errors.email">Email must be a valid email address</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Password</label>
                        <input type="password" formControlName="password" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.password.errors }" />
                        <div *ngIf="submitted && f.password.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                            <div *ngIf="f.password.errors.required">Password is required</div>
                            <div *ngIf="f.password.errors.minlength">Password must be at least 6 characters</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button [disabled]="loading" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {

   registerForm: FormGroup;
    submitted = false;

    constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            firstName: ['', Validators.required],
            lastName: ['', Validators.required],
            email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
            password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]]
        });
    }

    // convenience getter for easy access to form fields
    get f() { return this.registerForm.controls; }

    onSubmit() {
        this.submitted = true;

        // stop here if form is invalid
        if (this.registerForm.invalid) {
            return;
        }

        alert('SUCCESS!! :-)')
    }
}
```

my Working Stackblitz url

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mbagcm

Comment: Based on the elements present in array, do you need validations?

Comment: Yes i mean we have fields like firstname,lastname,age,gender in template  and i have an array like  data = {firstname,genger}.  i dont want to apply validation to all fields what ever name mentioned in the data only that fields i have to apply validation

Comment: go with FormArray,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this.formBuilder.group({ ABC: new FormArray([]),
```

now.

```
const abcFormArray = this.formBuilder.controls['ABC'] as FormArray;

Items = [Firstname, Lastname]

Items.forEach(() => {
// do your condition :-
abcFormArray.push((new FormControl(''))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the validators for fields based on condition like below

```
requiredValids: string[] = ['firstName', 'gender'];

this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  firstName: ['', this.requiredValids.indexOf('firstName') != -1 ? [Validators.required] : []],
  lastName: ['', this.requiredValids.indexOf('lastName') != -1 ? [Validators.required] : []],
  email: ['', this.requiredValids.indexOf('email') != -1 ? [Validators.required, Validators.email] : []],
  password: ['', this.requiredValids.indexOf('password') != -1 ? [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)] : []]
});
```

Working [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t3b9cm)

Comment: a small favour i am trying to create the dynamic form using an array i stuck some where while creating the form and thought  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-awguej

Comment: @Dexter Then you can try `FormArray` as suggested by **Var** in the answers